# Solving a system consisting of an ODE and a non-differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I would like to solve the following system of equations:

```
y'[t] == x[t]*y[t] - x[t];
10 == x[t]*y[t]/(x[t] + y[t]) + x[t]/(x[t] + y[t]^2)
```

Is there any way to solve this equations with *Mathematica*?

Comment: Have you tried solving them?  If you have, what result did you get?

Comment: Try reading documentation - there are examples:  [Differential-Algebraic equation](http://wolfram.com/xid/0dekz2-osn)

Comment: @Vitaliy Something seems to be wrong with how v9 handles these equations: first, `NDSolve[{y'[t] == x[t]*y[t] - x[t],
  10 == x[t]*y[t]/(x[t] + y[t]) + x[t]/(x[t] + y[t]^2)}, {x, y}, {t, 
  0, 10}]` does give a solution even though initial conditions are missing.  Second, `NSolve[{10 == (x y)/(x + y) + x/(x + y^2), x == 1}, {x, y}]` does not give a solution, even though `Solve` for the same equation does.  Do you also think there's a bug here?  Version 8 has neither of the problems: it correctly complains about the lack of initial conditions and `NSolve` does return a result for that eq.

Comment: initial condition?

Comment: @Szabolcs sorry, I used the same thing in my answer without reading your comment before

Comment: @Szabolcs I'll take a look, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
sol = NDSolve[{y'[t] == x[t]*y[t] - x[t],
   10 == x[t]*y[t]/(x[t] + y[t]) + x[t]/(x[t] + y[t]^2), 
   x[0] == 1/14 (-50 + 2 Sqrt[65]), y[0] == 2}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 20}];

ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: In V9.0.1 your `NDSolve` expression fails with the following message: 'NDSolve::ndcf: Repeated convergence test failure at t == 15.489851117996881`; unable to continue. >>'

Comment: @m_goldberg Sorry, v8 here ...

Comment: Not sure there is anything to be sorry about. I only wanted to point out that OP's problem may be a V.9 issue.